# Grunt task duplicate key

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a grunt file with tasks and jshint giving me a warning for duplicate keys on below:

```
       clean: ['public', 'build', 'css/main.css', 'css/print.css'],

        clean : {
            aftertest :['js/libs']
        },
```

How can I make this in one key, so that by default it runs `['public', 'build', 'css/main.css', 'css/print.css']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [different targets](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) for this.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  clean: {
    build: ['public', 'build', 'css/main.css', 'css/print.css'],
    aftertest: ['js/libs']
  }
});
```

Then in your build alias you might want to use it like so:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean:build', 'stylus', 'jade', 'jshint']);
```

Whenever you have more than a single target for one task, it's best to explicitly name them so that you'll know, in the future, what each target's *purpose* is.

Answer (score 1):

The error it's because the object you are passing to grunt.initConfig has two keys with the same name.

This is a Gruntfile.js example for gjslint task

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
      tasks: ['jshint', 'qunit']
    },
    gjslint: {
      options: {
        flags: [
          '--nojsdoc'
        ],
        reporter: {
          name: 'console'
        }
      },
      app: {
        src: ['www/app/**/*.js']
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-gjslint');
  grunt.registerTask('build', 'Grunt build taskt...', function() {
    grunt.log.write('you can log here some stuff...').ok();
  });

};
```